# Finding adjoint operator $\mathbb R_2[x] \to \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $V=\mathbb R_2[x]$ be a vector space.
Let us define the inner product of $V$ as:
$$\langle p,q\rangle=\int_0^1p(x)q(x)\,dx$$

Let $W=\mathbb R$ be a space and $T:V\to W$ a linear transformation for which $T(p(x)) = p(0)$. How do I find $T^*$?

I've seen that this question was asked a few times on this site but couldn't find a question that is similar in mine (as in a similar linear transformation and vector space).

I've defined $T$ as $T=(1,0,0)$ over the standard base $\{1,x,x^2\}$, and I know I need to look for $T^*$ for which this equation holds: $\langle Tp,q\rangle =\langle p,T^*q\rangle  \forall p,q \in \mathbb R_2[x]$.

Would love to see a solution to this one, thanks!

Comment: you should note that $Tp \notin \mathbb R_2[x]$. It is a member of $\mathbb R$.  The inner products on each side of the equality are different. Hence, your last statement does not make sense as written. Adjoints really only make sense (usually) for $T:V \to V$.